# JSON.NET Parsing Full Key-Value Pair as Key

Tags: c#, json, json.net, asp.net-web-api2, custom-attributes

I'm rolling my own `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute for Web API 2.2 for one of my controllers that processes form data through AJAX calls.

I'm sending the data to my controller as JSON and it looks like this (pulled from Fiddler):

```
{"__RequestVerificationToken":"E8EoBCaFbqSOXhQZiuM93jciTcOAYeLjZj682-3SZRaQ6OOtrm-caZI_IWnX1FH_nwe_AuWnWwxy5ulS0Ynz0STlNptqN09Lu69HxyTeA9PUln8h73yjahB24QPxqI010","ProjectInfo.Description":"Test Description 2"}
```

I was trying to get the `__RequestVerificationToken` data like this, but it's not working:

```
JToken json = (JToken)actionContext.ActionArguments["json"];
formToken = (string)json["__RequestVerificationToken"];
```

`formToken` keeps containing null values so through some debugging I've found that the entire JSON value is being considered a Key, with an empty value as seen in the screenshot below:

[image: Values as Keys]

I'm not sure why this is happening, since the JSON appears to be valid.  Fiddler is able to parse the JSON without issues in it's built in Json Viewer, but JSON.NET appears to be sticking the entire json string as the Key instead of parsing it.  I know that I could hack it and manually parse out the value I need from the key, but that's dirty as I rather this be done properly.

Is there something wrong with my JSON or method that I'm using to obtain it, or is there a bug in the json.net library/asp.net causing this behavior?  Any idea why this might be happening?

**EDIT:**

It's possible that somehow the data is being serialized twice, but I'm not sure why/how.  From my debugger here's the stringified value of `json`:

```
Root = {
"{\"__RequestVerificationToken\":\"yqob-3bUW8C8sUrHWu_feRFOz2KPUKqugo1QoN2s8v9UhlMTwSonxoEdnh85TdM56Xj-aixZdgSQXs8D6ureAQTU83wVtvsoLBd2tDl0ZPyq_2sFefObQx0VHOExQjgh0\",\"ProjectInfo.Description\":\"Test Description\"}": ""
}
```

Here's the code that generates the JSON on the client side.  It's a jQuery extension:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function () {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } 
        else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

This is then called as such in the submit method:

```
$('#description-editable form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = JSON.stringify($(this).serializeObject());

    //ajax method for PUT here...

});
```

Comment: Is it possible that the JSON has been serialized twice? This would explain why JSON.NET thinks the entire string is a single value instead of an object

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker It's definitely possible.  Take a look at my edit from the data in the debugger

Comment: Can you show the code that's creating the JSON?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Do you mean the JavaScript generating it on the client side?

Comment: Yep. I don't think you need to call `JSON.stringify` here. Can you try without it?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Woo! That fixed it.  Thanks!  Feel free to write an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Sure--to give a more detailed answer could you show your AJAX options? I'm not sure why stringifying would break things...

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker I kind of cheated and didn't use `Ajax.BeginForm`, but instead used `Html.BeginForm("controller/method", "api")` so that might have been why this happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what your AJAX options are, but it looks like your object is being stringified twice before it gets sent up. You should be able to remove the `stringify` call:

```
$('#description-editable form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serializeObject();

    //ajax method for PUT here...

});
```